# JSP + thymeleaf with springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hello Im trying to combine JSP and HTML from thymeleaf in one project, Unfortunately I'm stuck. I'm not able to configure properly the cooperation of both TemplateResolver and InternalResourceViewResolver. 
here is my application code:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:config.xml")
public class Application {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/webapp/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="jsp/*"></property>
    <property name="order" value="1"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Thymeleaf -->
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="templates/*"></property>
    <property name="order" value="0"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/templates" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

this is the structure of my project:
https://s31.postimg.org/oti25mxp7/springbootproject.png

when I ask the controller for jsp or html file i got

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "personview", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "hello", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

my Pom.xml (only dependencies)

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you also post your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to move templates to WEB-INF directory.

To enable jsp resolving change declaration of

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
```

to

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
```

Comment: did as you said but no effect, maybe there is something with my classpath?

Comment: Try to change "/webapp/WEB-INF/views/" in InternalResourceViewResolver to /WEB-INF/views/. Also move templates to /WEB-INF/templates/ and change templateResolver prefix to /WEB-INF/templates

Comment: Did this answer helped you?